# Validar input para evitar espacios en blanco o que quede vacío

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Aqui esta un pequeño ejemplo*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="api_crud_form" name="api_crud_form" action="https://www.google.es">
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#api_crud_form').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#nombre').val() == '') {
                alert("Ingresar Nombre");
            } 
            else{
              alert("se envio los datos");
            }
    });
  });

</script>
```

> Aqui esta un pequeño ejemplo

**Es  un ejemplo que valida si el  este vacio pero no valida si insertar espacios vacios**

> ¿Cómo puedo validar los espacios vacíos?

Comment: No entiendo, ¿cuál es la pregunta?, además ¿por qué tu pregunta en el título dice *closed*?

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es validar mis <input> que no inserten espacios vacios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy seguro que te refieres a validar que el input no esté vacío y que no contenga espacios en blanco. Para eso ocupa la función de javascript [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) que básicamente lo que hace es limpiar de espacios un string por la izquierda y derecha, esto permite limpiar de espacios cadenas de texto.

También, usaremos [`length`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) para contar los caracteres de la cadena recogida con `jQuery` desde el input en cuestión:

Ejemplo:

```js
function verificar() {
  if ( $("#nombre-input").val().trim().length > 0 ) {
    alert("El campo contiene un string válido que no son espacios");
  }
  else {
    alert("El campo contiene espacios y está vacío");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label>Nombre:</label>
<input id="nombre-input" type="text">
<input type="button" onclick="verificar()" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Lo probé usando jQuery 1.2

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas queda perfecto y mas corto con JS puro de este modo:

**Formulario**

```
<h1>Formulario de envío</h1>
<form id="api_crud_form" name="api_crud_form" action="https://www.google.es">
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"><br>
    <button id="envio">Envio</button>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  let envio = document.getElementById("envio")
  let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre")

  envio.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (nombre.value === "") {
        alert("ingresa algo")
    } else {
        alert(`ok todo ok: ${nombre.value.trim()}`)
    }
  })
```

Lo que hacemos es:

- Obtener el `input` de envío y verificamos primero si el valor de la propiedad `value` es igual a `""` lo cual indica que el usuario no escribió y entonces avisamos en concecuencia
- En caso contrario al punto anterior para eliminar los espacio en blanco usamos el método `trim()` encadenándolo al nombre de la variable con la cual obtuvimos el `input` donde el usuario escribió

**Referencia**

- [Método `trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim)

Comment: Gracias amigo por la informacion si me ayudo a hubicarme :)

Comment: como permitir en powershell que: al realizar un read-host "Ecribe algo:". si no escribo nada o haga un espacio no me de rojo

Comment: y como valido un input es que aver soy estudiantey estoy aprendiendo y no me han enseñado eso lo quiero hacer por curiosidad